# upload file using inputstream in GAE java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, file-upload, apache-commons-fileupload

I am trying to upload file to google sites and am obtaining the stream using apache commons file upload. 
I get the input stream as under

```
    InputStream is = fileItem.openStream();
```

How will I convert this input stream in file object so that below call succeeds and I am able to set the MediaFileSource to above converted file.

```
AttachmentEntry newAttachment = new AttachmentEntry();
newAttachment.setMediaSource(new MediaFileSource(file, fileMimeType));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`MediaStreamSource`](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/javadoc/com/google/gdata/data/media/MediaStreamSource.html) instead of `MediaFileSource`.

Comment: Thanx @BalusC , everything is working fine till I get this ServiceException that says "Not authorized to write to this feed"

Comment: com.google.gdata.util.ServiceForbiddenException: OK
Not authorized to write to this feed

Answer (score 1):

You have no write access to a file system on AppEngine and you're supposed to keep your data in datastore. However, [gaefs project](http://code.google.com/p/gaevfs/) gives you a virtual file system and, as to the best pf my knowledge, supports file uploading.

Comment: I would prefer to upload directly from stream object, is it possible to customize the MediaFileSource in any way so that it takes *stream object

Comment: Did you look at the code of gaefs servlet? It reads from a stream. You may also read App Engine docs: http://code.google.com/appengine/kb/java.html#fileforms